# Under which condition does $Q>I_n$ result in $Q^2>I_n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider an $n\times n$ real matrix $Q>I_n$ (i.e., $Q-I_n$ is positive definite).

Under which condition, $Q^2>I_n$ also holds?

It is easy to show that if $Q$ is diagonalizable, $Q>I_n$ results in $Q^2>I_n$. But I look for more general conditions on matrix $Q$.

Comment: A square matrix $A$ is called diagonalizable if it is similar to a diagonal matrix, i.e., if there exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^{−1}AP$ is a diagonal matrix.

Comment: Does $Q^2-I_n=Q^2-I_n^2=(Q-I_n)(Q+I_n)$ help?

Comment: All symmetric matrices are unitarily (orthogonally) diagonalizable. And positive definite matrices are symmetric, by definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always true. Since $Q-I$ is positive definite, $Q$ is symmetric and thus diagonalizable. Also all eigenvalues of $Q$ are larger than $1$, i.e. $\lambda_i>1$. This means that $\lambda_i^2>1$. Since $\lambda_i^2$ is also eigenvalues of $Q^2$, we have $Q^2>I$.